# How to add no Proxy in java for a given ip address as in mozilla

Tags: java

I am reading xml in java via url, this is my code:

```
String web="example.com";
URL url = new URL(web);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

conn.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

writer.write(ufx);
writer.flush();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   answer.append(line);
}
writer.close();
reader.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}

return answer.toString();
```

My problem is that the web url that I am using is blocked,  and I want to read data from the web via input stream. The web opens successfully in mozilla after removing no proxy in mozilla. 
How do I achieve this in java ?

Comment: Although I have provided an answer on how to set proxy for java ,I am a bit confused, in your question heading you say `How to add no Proxy in java` and then in the question description you are saying `The web opens successfully in mozilla after removing no proxy in mozilla` , which seems completely opposite. So which one do you want `proxy` or `no proxy` ?

Comment: I dont want to use proxy for a given ip address

Answer (score 27):

There are system properties which specify the proxy configuration used by java. You can pass them as command line arguments, or set them first thing in your application:

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=1.1.1.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=1234 -jar somejar.jar
```

Note that there are more, and you can also set different proxy settings for different protocols like http, https, and you can also specify exceptions.

**To define an exception (not to use proxy)**, you can use the `http.nonProxyHosts` system property, for example:

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=webcache.example.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
    -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="localhost|host.example.com"
```

Check more info on [Official Oracle documentation.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html)

Answer (score 4):

Since you are not using a programmatic proxy, it is using the system properties:

- http.proxyHost
- http.proxyPort
- http.nonProxyHosts

You can either not set them or update the last one.

**UPDATE**

Upon rereading your question I'm actually not sure whether you **want** to use a proxy or you **don't want** to use one. Can you specify? Either way the properties can help you or you can look at URL.openConnection(Proxy)

Comment: I dont want to use proxy for a given ip address

Comment: Then don't set the properties for the jvm or explicitly add a bypass for the host you want in the last property

Comment: Dude, it's a system property, just set it or don't set it when you start the vm...

Comment: This is the error am getting:java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL:

Comment: This is the part of the code that I changed:  URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(Proxy.NO_PROXY);

Answer (score 0):

Add following lines of code to your source :-

```
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyUser", "");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPassword", "");
```

Since you do not want to use proxy , you can provide blank values to the proxy settings

or you can do change settings using java control panel:-

> In the Java Control Panel, under the General tab, click on Network Settings.
>   Select the Use Browser Settings checkbox.
>   Click OK to save your changes.

[Reference for properties](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/http-proxy-setting-java-setting-proxy-java/)

Comment: The settings in the Java Control Panel affect only applets and Java Web Start apps. Standalone apps have to manage proxies themselves.